# How to extract data (tag_book and bicycle) from json response using JMETER

Tags: json, regex, jmeter, response

```
    {
    "store": {
        "tag_book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

I wish to extract just tag_book and bicycle. I dont need values of tag_book and bicycle.

Can you please explain how to extract the same.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above response
2. Put the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).store.eachWithIndex { entry, i ->
       vars.put('var_' + (i + 1), entry.getKey())
   }
   ```

   where:

   - `prev` stands for previous [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)
   - `vars` is for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)
3. This will generate the following [JMeter Varibales](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

   ```
   var_1=tag_book
   var_2=bicycle
   ```

   You will be able to use them as `${var_1}`, `${var_2}`, etc. where required.

Comment: Can we do it with JSON Extractor?